# FreeIPA : Keytab File for Adding Multiple NFS Clients

Tags: centos7, freeipa

I'm relatively new to IPA and have been practicing setting up `Kerberized NFS.` I succeeded in initially sharing a directory from my VM `Server1` to `Server2`.

I accomplished the above by adding the `NFS` service in my `IPA Server` for `server1` and generated a `keytab file` :

```
ipa service-add nfs/server1.example.com

ipa-getkeytab -s ipa.example.com -p nfs/server1.example.com -k /root/krb5.keytab
```

and then copied the `Keytab` file from the `IPA Server` to `server1` and `server2`.

Now I'm trying to share a directory from `server2` to `server1`.

Should the same `keytab` file work because right now as I'm unable to mount a kerberos share but normal shares **without** `sec=krb5p` works.

Secondly in case of generating a new keytab file how would I go about it. I want krb security from both server1 to server2 and vice versa. Operating system is `Centos7.3`

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I tried adding `NFS` service for both clients :

```
ipa service-add nfs/server1.example.com
ipa service-add nfs/server2.example.com
```

generated a `Keytab` file for both and used `ktutil` to merge the `keytab` files :

```
ipa-getkeytab -s ipa.example.com -p nfs/server1.example.com -k /home/krbserver1.keytab
ipa-getkeytab -s ipa.example.com -p nfs/server2.example.com -k /home/krbserver2.keytab
```

Output of klist -k :

```
[root@server1 etc]# klist -k
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 nfs/server1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3 nfs/server1.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 nfs/server2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2 nfs/server2.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Sadly this didn't work either and now both shares are getting `access denied`!

When I added the service for `nfs/server2.example.com` only I was able to share from `server2` to `server1` but now it was not available from `server1` to `server2`.

How can I get it to work both ways? Any help would be greatly appreciated.